# How to start from root activity after task killer killed my app?

Tags: android, android-activity

After task killer kills app when I am in sub activity and I restart app, it starts from sub activity and crashes.
It calls onCreate() of sub activity not onResume().

But when I push home button and restart my app, it starts from onResume() of sub activity.
So, there is no problem in this case.

Is there any way to start from root activity after killed by task killer and start from sub activity after killed by home button?

Answer (score -1):

Set this in your activity element in you app manifest:

```
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

Comment: It still calls onCreate of sub activity. I think it works only for root activity.